# numpy 2D Histogram

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, histogram2d

When I run:

```
hist_2d_i = np.histogram2d(df.feature1.iloc[0], df.feature2.iloc[0], bins=\
[binsx, binsy],weights=df.weights.iloc[0])
```

I get an error:
The dimension of bins must be equal to the dimension of the  sample x.

But if I run:

```
hist_2d_i = np.histogram2d(df.feature1.iloc[0:1], df.feature2.iloc[0:1], bins=\
[binsx, binsy],weights=df.weights.iloc[0:1])
```

It works as expected. What is the difference?

The index runs through the number of samples in the pandas dataframe dataset.

isn't `[0] == [0:1]` as index ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[0]` is the first element of an array, while `[0:1]` is an array containing only the first element.

Comment: Okay so as long as it's an array of 1 element, it works. Thanks!